# Как исправить ошибку Android Source Generator: AndroidManifest.xml file not found

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Как исправить ошибку? До этого была ошибка "Setup SDK", вроде разобрался, а теперь вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не делайте скрины, вставьте ошибку текстом

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста как это проверить??  Error:Android Source Generator: [програмирование] AndroidManifest.xml file not found